# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'breezyslam'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, robotics, slam

while using this [package](https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM) i am getting this error, even after installing

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQuAR.png)

Comment: please copy the error in the body of your question and remove the image.

Comment: Not leaving the error logs makes it hard to understand what the problem is.  Include steps that go you to this point.